# Extracting entries in a file base from reference point using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could you provide me an example in python how to extract text entries using starting reference and the end reference point?  For example the file "test.txt" has content as follows:

*** start123
1234567
abcdefg
xyz1234
*** end123

I want python to search for "*** start123" once found, look for end point "*** end123" then any entries in between are extracted and saved into a new file "test2.txt" as is. I know it can be done in grep or awk but if you could provide me a sample in python, I could reuse that to accomplish my next step.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd use regex. Try using [`import re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for text matching in general.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `str.find()`. This method returns the index where the substring was found or -1 if it wasn't found. I'll leave the I/O and error checking for you to implement. Thus you will have the substrings occurrences in the line and you can slice your string to get just the content between them.

```
>>> string = "* start123 1234567 abcdefg xyz1234 * end123"
>>> st = string.find('* start123')
>>> ed = string.find('* end123')
>>> string[st+len('* start123 '):ed-1]
'1234567 abcdefg xyz1234'
```

Just make sure to deal with the case in which the substrings aren't found.